# High Precision Time Stamps method calls fail due to procedure entry point in dll Kernel32.dll, GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()

Tags: windows, visual-c++

High Precision Time Stamps method calls fail due to procedure entry point in dll Kernel32.dll. 
I want to change time stamps from 14:17:06:942 to add micro and partial nanoseconds. e.g. 14:17:06:942.381.2 
How does one track down missing dependency libraries ? I am using a fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 , Desktop development with C++ included work load.

The Failing message is : The procedure entry point GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.
This message is only shown when running from Visual Studio. From a direct console launch or desktop mouse launch there is no message.

Fails on
 Windows 7Pro SP1
 Windows Server 2012 R2

Works on
 Mac Catalina Parallels Windows VM Server with Windows 10

MS Docs reference, in section QPC Support in Windows versions, says this should work on WS Server 2012 R2 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps

MS Studio output :
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Art\source\repos\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x00000000778C85B8 (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
The thread 0x2538 has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139).
The program '[14284] ConsoleApplication4.exe' has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.

Source Code Here:

```
#include iostream
#include windows.h
#include sysinfoapi.h


int main()
{

std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

LPFILETIME lpSystemTimeAsFileTime = { 0 };
GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(lpSystemTimeAsFileTime);

ULARGE_INTEGER u = { 0 };

memcpy(&u, lpSystemTimeAsFileTime, sizeof(u));
// // u. = u.QuadPart && 0xFF
UINT16 nanos = u.QuadPart % 10;
UINT16 micros = u.QuadPart / 10 % 1000;
UINT16 millis = u.QuadPart / 10000 % 1000;

//  memcpy(&ft, &u, sizeof(ft));
SYSTEMTIME st = { 0 };
FileTimeToSystemTime(lpSystemTimeAsFileTime, &st);

wprintf(L"%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
    st.wDay, st.wMonth, st.wYear, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond);


std::cout << "Press any key to terminate \n";

char c;
std::cin >> c;
}
```

Comment: Win8 or higher required.

Comment: Thanks , I tested on Windows Server 2012 R2 as well. Maybe I have something missing from my Win Server 2012 R2 machine ? This is from the MS Web site I referenced earlier and I think my machine qualifies to run that procedure. Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2012 R2 use TSCs as the basis for the performance counter. The TSC synchronization algorithm was significantly improved to better accommodate large systems with many processors.

Comment: Okay I think I am past the issue which it should work on Win Server 2012. I tried Dependency walker and it showed some missing dlls . Google showed some of the DLL's were for Debug build. Creating a release build dependency walker showed no missing DLLS and the Code ran , we'll actually I had to fix things to make it work further .